# How do I change the DPI of only one application, "/usr/bin/wps"?

Tags: linux-mint, dpi

How do I change the DPI of only one application: "**/usr/bin/wps**"? 
On [**this page**](https://superuser.com/a/1302811/379513), I found the following script but don't know which part(s) should be replaced with "**/usr/bin/wps**".

```
#!/usr/bin/bash                                                 
OLDDPI=$(xrdb -query | awk '/Xft.dpi/ {print $2}')
xrdb -merge <(echo "Xft.dpi: 108")
$* & disown
```

I don't have to restore it to the default after a number of seconds/minutes.

Comment: I don't get why you say “I don't have to restore it to the default after a number of seconds/minutes.”?

Comment: I want to permanently change the DPI. I don't have to restore the DPI to the default.

Comment: Why did you think that we would think otherwise. What am I missing here?

Comment: The original script will restore the DPI to the original value after three seconds.

Comment: The script there is intended to be provided a command to run as arguments. It also sets the DPI back to the original value after a short while so that it "only" affects the application it launches. If you don't set it back, it will affect every subsequently launched application

Comment: Do you it is impossible to change DPI permanently in a way that will only affect "**/usr/bin/wps**"?

Comment: Yes, DPI is not application-specific. That script is a hacky work-around

Comment: Is your question: “How do I make it so that when I run `wps…` it runs `this_script /usr/bin/wps …`?